# cross platform usb drive encryption

Tags: encryption, usb-flash-drive, cross-platform

not sure if this is the correct place to ask this but is there a way to encrypt a usb flash drive across all platforms? (mac and windows) I'd prefer if I didn't have to use a third party program

Answer (score 1):

[VeraCrypt](https://www.veracrypt.fr/en/Home.html) is a free open source disk encryption software for Windows, Mac and Linux. VeraCrypt can encrypt an entire partition or storage device such as a USB flash drive or hard drive.

Answer (score 0):

Well, it might not be direct solution for you, but it's worth to mention. For me it is very usable sometimes:

1) Just select all contents, right click and select ADD TO ARCHIVE.

2) In Archive settings, set "STORE"(as method) and set password.

Then you can just extract the contents on another PC.